# Counting distincts in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database which looks like the following:

```
Source   quoted    sold
google     1         0
google     0         0
google     1         1
google     1         0
google     1         1
direct     1         0
direct     0         0
direct     1         1
google     1         0
```

I want to count the number of people who quoted which came from google, and the number who purchased who came from google in the same line, as well as the other sources. So the above results would look like

```
Source  quotes   solds
google    5        2
direct    2        1
another   23       5   (not noted above, but there are countless more)
```

How can I get this information in SQL?

Comment: Let's have 400 identical answers to this question, shall we? Next time can you *try* something first? Also can you tell us if `quoted` and `sold` are `BIT` columns? If so then all of the answers are wrong.

Comment: -1 @AaronBertrand said it already... please search before you post, this is SQL 101

Comment: @AaronBertrand, Love2Learn I dont know what to search for. I have tried count and distinct and variying combinations of them, but I thought I'd avoid over complicating the question by not describing something which is not the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like a simple `SUM` with `GROUP BY` would work:

```
SELECT Source, SUM(quoted), SUM(Sold)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Source
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of the umpteen duplicates I'll offer a different perspective, in case those columns are `BIT` columns. If they are, the current queries will yield:

> Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 14
>   Operand data type bit is invalid for sum operator.

To work around this you can use one of the following structs:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(Source VARCHAR(32), quoted BIT, sold BIT);

INSERT @t VALUES
('google',1,0),
('google',0,0),
('google',1,1),
('google',1,0),
('google',1,1),
('direct',1,0),
('direct',0,0),
('direct',1,1),
('google',1,0);

SELECT Source, 
    COUNT(NULLIF(quoted,0)), 
    COUNT(NULLIF(sold,  0))
 FROM @t
 GROUP BY Source;

SELECT Source, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN quoted = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    SUM(CASE WHEN sold   = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
 FROM @t
 GROUP BY Source;

SELECT Source, 
    SUM(CONVERT(INT, quoted)),
    SUM(CONVERT(INT, sold))
 FROM @t
 GROUP BY Source;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you're looking for...

```
SELECT source, SUM(quoted), SUM(sold)
FROM your_table
GROUP BY source.
```

Answer (score 2):

This requires a basic `GROUP BY` syntax, and your database is perfectly setup for this:

```
select source, sum(quoted) quoted, sum(sold) sold
from your_table
group by source;
```

Comment: Only "perfectly" if those columns are not `BIT` columns, in which case this fails...

Answer (score -3):

```
SELECT source, SUM(quoted = 1) AS quotes, SUM(solds = 1) AS solds
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY Source
```

Comment: `SUM(quoted = 1)` does not seem to be valid T-SQL - where does that come from? I get `Msg 102 - Incorrect syntax near ')'.`

Comment: This answer is valid in MySQL (and possibly in SQLite) but not in SQL-Server.